# Default function argument with generic types

Tags: scala, generics, default-value

My function gets another function (which is mapping input type to output type) as parameter:

```
type Handled[S,R] = S => R

def myFunc[S,R](value: S, handled: Handled[S,R] = defaultHandled): R = {
  handled(value)
}
```

I need to write defaultHandled function which will get input type and return it as is.

So by default i want to map input type to output type where input type is the same as output type. This function should simply pass input to output for any input type.
How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While technically this is possible:

```
type Handled[S, R] = S => R

def defaultHandled[S, R](x: S): R = x.asInstanceOf[R]

def myFunc[S, R](value: S, handled: Handled[S, R] = defaultHandled[S, R] _): R = {
  handled(value)
}

myFunc[Int, Int](1)
```

It's not type safe and generally not a good idea. For example, if you try to call `myFunc` with different type parameters while still relying on default `handled` value, you'll get runtime exception:

```
myFunc[Int, String](1)

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

---

Scala way to address this is to have handled as implicit parameter. In this case you can supply default implementation which compiler will use it possible.

```
type Handled[S, R] = S => R

implicit def defaultHandled[S]: Handled[S, S] = identity

def myFunc[S, R](value: S)(implicit handled: Handled[S, R]): R = {
  handled(value)
}

myFunc(1) // compiles and works

myFunc[Int, String](1) // compilation error: Error:(11, 21) No implicit view 
                       // available from Int => String.
                       //myFunc[Int, String](1)
                       //            ^
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that for this specific case there is a simple solution which achieves exactly the result you want: just replace the default parameter by an overload.

```
type Handled[S,R] = S => R

def myFunc[S,R](value: S, handled: Handled[S,R]): R = {
  handled(value)
}

def myFunc[S](value: S): S = value
```

Answer (score 0):

If `S` and `R` are two arbitrary types (that don't depend on each other) then I guess it's impossible (without run-time casting). You should provide `defaultHandled` for every `S`, `R`. And `s => s` is of type `S => S`, not `S => R` for arbitrary `R`.

But if type `R` **depends on type** `S` then you can consider doing the following:

```
  trait Handled[S] {
    type R
    def apply(s: S): R
  } 
  object Handled {
    type Aux[S, R0] = Handled[S] {type R = R0}
    def apply[S, R0](f: S => R0): Aux[S, R0] = new Handled[S] {
      override type R = R0
      override def apply(s: S): R = f(s)
    }
  }


  def myFunc[S](value: S, handled: Handled[S] = Handled[S, S](s => s)): handled.R = {
    handled(value)
  }
```

Here `Handled[S]` (on contrary to `Handled.Aux[S, R]`) is an [existential type](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/existential-types-in-scala).